# Debugging missing DHCP "request" on a closed embedded device

Tags: dhcp

I have an embedded device (control hub for the Philips Hue lighting system) that connects to my home network and uses DHCP.  Everything was working fine for months, until I was forced to change routers.  Now, the hub can't get an IP address at all.  I'm trying to figure out what the problem might be but there's one major catch: the hub's only interface is web-based.  When it doesn't have an IP address, there's no way to get any information from the hub or send it any commands.  How can I debug this when I have no access to the problematic device?

I flashed DD-WRT onto my router (Linksys N600) to get more configuration options, but nothing helped.  I disabled DHCP on the router and set up a Raspberry Pi as a DHCP server, and I the DHCP logs are a repeating sequence that looks like this:

```
Feb 18 19:36:06 retropie dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:17:88:6f:30:78 via eth0
Feb 18 19:36:06 retropie dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.1.150 to 00:17:88:6f:30:78 via eth0
Feb 18 19:36:09 retropie dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:17:88:6f:30:78 via eth0
Feb 18 19:36:09 retropie dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.1.150 to 00:17:88:6f:30:78 via eth0
Feb 18 19:36:12 retropie dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:17:88:6f:30:78 via eth0
Feb 18 19:36:12 retropie dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.1.150 to 00:17:88:6f:30:78 via eth0
```

The server offers an address, but the hub never sends a "request" packet for some reason.  None of the other myriad of devices on my network have any DHCP problems.  I can't go back to the old router, it was built into my DSL modem and we don't use DSL any more.

I'm not much of a network guy.  Can anyone suggest how I might approach this problem when the fault seems to be inside a closed device?

Comment: Have you tried a hard reset of the Philips Hue bridge?

Comment: @joeqwerty- Yes, even swapped out the bridge for a brand new one.  I can connect to the bridge using a friend's router and set a static IP, but once back on my network I can't see it or get any sort of response from it.